# Using EMF objects as keys

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf

Is it possible to have EMF objects implement `hashCode` and `equals`? I would like to be able to use a model object as a key in a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EObject's [javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EObject.html) is clear about that. An EObject may not specialize `hashCode` or `equals`. However, you can use them in maps as long as you are aware of the identity semantics of `Object#equals(..)` and `#hashCode`.

Comment: Well, I can't. I need different EObjects to compare equals based on values on certain attributes.

Comment: Why do you need that? If you want to have semantics of value objects, you should use EDataTypes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm by no means an EMF expert but you could create a wrapper object for the EObject and implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in the wrapper in terms of the attributes from the EObject you are interested in and then use that wrapper as the key. That would force you always to instantiate a wrapper object when searching the map, but depending on the usage pattern that may not be too hateful.

Be aware that using mutable objects as keys in a map is tricky. If the object is mutated after being used as a key in such a way that the hash code changes then it may be difficult to find the key again later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EcoreUtil.equals()`, if the algorithm behind the method suits your use case.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can implement (generate) `equals` / `hashCode` methods for each `EMF-*Impl` class. You have  to insert a `@generated not` comment above the method header.